# If I use my external IP to talk to a device on the LAN, will the traffic go through the outside internet?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

So, say I had an SSH server on my LAN that was being port forwarded to the outside network. If I connect to that SSH server using the external IP with a computer connected to the LAN, will the traffic go through the internet or will the traffic just go straight to the SSH server through the LAN?

Here's a bad diagram showing the network setup:

[image: Diagram showing my PC and an SSH server connected to a router via LAN]

Comment: Install and use `tracepath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, the traffic will go to your router, and then from your router to the server.

So not entirely LAN only, but not leaving the premesis either.